how to create a quiz document positioning an image in one corner, and users name and id in the title line
I edited this question with an mwe.
Here is code that avoids using title to almost achieve what I want.
Oddly, the title of the quiz comes out on the next line.
I don't understand how this is possible. If anything, I thought it would wrap and the section would go to the next line. So I created a table, and the quiz title (it is parameter #2, right?) still goes to the next line.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Include TikZ package for drawing
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{questioncount}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1 cm,0.75cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Define the quiz environment
\newcommand{\squiz}[2][]{%
  \begin{document}
  \title{\noindent}
  \author{}
  \date{}
  \setlength{\droptitle}{-2.5cm} % Adjust the vertical space of the title
  \maketitle
  \vspace*{-3.5cm}
  \begin{flushleft}

    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
          &   &    & \small{Name} & \small{NetID} & \small{Section} \\
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo.png}  & #1 & #2 & \ans{5} & \ans{2.5} & \ans{1} \\
      \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    \hrule
}

\newcommand{\equiz}{%
    \end{document}
}

\squiz{mycourse}{quiz title}
  \q{10} $2+2=$ \ans{2}
\equiz


it's not strictly wrong but a definition of \newcommand{\quiz}[2]{%     \begin{document} is exceedingly weird and will confuse any syntax highlighting in editors and any humans looking at the document, as there will be an \end{document} with no visible \begin

@cfr Yes but if you make end document explicit should do the same to begin document

@DavidCarlisle A merely hypothetical imperative?

This is cobbled together from this and your other question, neither of which provided a clear example to work with. So this is partly guesswork and may not be what you intended. I assume, however, that the basic principle is the the same.
You really have no use for \maketitle here, so why use it? There is no law which requires every document to have one. When you end up with \title{\noindent} and little but attempts to undo the effects of \maketitle, you should rethink ;).
Unless you have another use for it, tikz is overkill. A simple \fbox suffices. The only disadvantage is that it means you need to either pass \ans{} a dimension every time or pass it a number every time. Obviously this could be managed, but not by me. (That is, I tried to accommodate both types of argument and ended up with errors complaining that I was using \dimexpr in horizontal mode. Since I have no idea what to do about this and don't really understand why it is a problem, I unsurprisingly failed abysmally to solve them.)
Note that an uncommented line ending inserts a space under the standard category code regime, so your code was adding a lot of spaces apparently in more-or-less arbitrary places. I've spaced the elements out equally along the horizontal line, but you can remove some of the \hfills if you want different spacing.
Note that this is going to fail if course and/or title are anything like the standard course IDs and titles I'm familiar with. They are just too long.
If you really want to maximise the use of vertical space rather than, say, having a second page (to save trees? photocopying? money? to satisfy some institutional rule?), you probably want to use something like enumitem and to configure your lists with no or less vertical space. I did not, however, do that here.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\fboxsep=0pt
\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{questioncount}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ans {  m }
{% tikz is surely overkill
  \fbox{\makebox(#1,0.75cm){}}%
}


\newcommand{\quiz}[2]{%
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo.png}\hfill
  \textbf{#1 #2} \hfill
  Name: \ans{6cm} \hfill NetID: \ans{4cm} \hfill Section \ans{1cm}%
  \vspace{0.5cm}%
  \par
  \hrule
}

\begin{document}
\quiz{course}{title}
\q{30} instructions
\begin{itemize}
  \item What voltage is nominal (ideal) for 74LS parts? \ans{2 cm}\,V
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

I've not got the hang of working around Okular's image bug, but:


Oh, and I moved \begin{document} out of the macro definition because it messes up code indentation in my editor, confuses me and seems like a potential source of trouble for no benefit.
