Created a quiz environment but error claims it can't find \begin{document}
I cleaned up code to create a quiz. I have an mwe using two commands squiz and equiz.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Include TikZ package for drawing
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{questioncount}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1 cm,0.75cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Define the quiz environment
\newcommand{\squiz}[2][]{%
  \begin{document}
  \title{\noindent}
  \author{}
  \date{}
  \setlength{\droptitle}{-2.5cm} % Adjust the vertical space of the title
  \maketitle
  \vspace*{-3.5cm}
    \begin{flushleft}
      \textbf{#1} \textbf{#2} \textbf{Name:} \ans{5} \textbf{NetID:} \ans{2.5} \textbf{section:} \ans{1} \\
    \end{flushleft}
    \hrule
}

\newcommand{\equiz}{%
    \end{document}
}

\squiz{mycourse}{quiz title}
  \q{10} $2+2=$ \ans{2}
\equiz

The above works, though it puts "quiz title" below the horizontal rule, which I don't understand.
I would prefer to create an environment, but I think it does not like putting \end{document} inside the environment?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{questioncount}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}

% Define the quiz environment
\newenvironment{quiz}[2][]{%
    \begin{document}
    \title{\noindent}
    \author{}
    \date{}
    \setlength{\droptitle}{-2.5cm} % Adjust the vertical space of the title
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{-2.5cm} 
    \textbf{#1} #2
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \hrule
}{%
    \end{document}
}

\begin{quiz}{course}{title}
  \q{10} test1
  \q{10} test2
\end{quiz}

This one gives an error saying that \end{document} is inside \end{quiz}
Is there simply no way to do this in latex?

How many versions of this code do you plan to ask about? You've already been told that putting \begin{document} inside a command is a Bad Idea. I don't think David was suggesting you instead use an environment with \end{document} obscured as well. In any case, this won't work. Why do you want to do this anyway? Just to save typing \end{document}? Doesn't your editor do that for you?

no, that isn't what i was told. I was told that \begin didn't match end. And yes, I don't want to write \begin{document} and \end{document} every time, but if I have to, I will.

David Carlisle and Alan Munn both told you it as a bad idea to put \begin{document} into a command. David said it would confuse both humans and editors. I forget exactly what Alan said.

David: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717670/how-to-create-a-quiz-document-positioning-an-image-in-one-corner-and-users-name#comment1784085_717670 ; Alan: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717671/missing-begindocument-error-with-macro#comment1784069_717671.

Note that you could - if you wanted to - wrap quiz into the document environment, if you specified the arguments in some alternative way in the preamble. I don't particularly recommend it because it makes your code less transparent, but it would be straightforward to implement. However, if your editor doesn't do this kind of thing for you, I'd find a new editor first.

Every environment adds a layer of localness (\begingroup ... \endgroup), except \document removes that layer with an extra \endgroup at the start.

You were almost there. But the definition of quiz is wrong in a few  ways.

You need to issue \endgroup.
The arguments are mandatory, if you want \begin{quiz}{course}{title}.
Why using \maketitle when everything is empty?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{questioncount}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}

% Define the quiz environment
\newenvironment{quiz}[2]{%
    \endgroup
    \begin{document}
    \textbf{#1} #2\par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \hrule
}{%
    \end{document}
}

\begin{quiz}{course}{title}
  \q{10} test1
  \q{10} test2
\end{quiz}

But is it worth the pain? The following is as easy to type and you don't risk breaking things.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{questioncount}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}

% Define the quiz environment
\newenvironment{quiz}[2]{%
    \textbf{#1} #2\par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \hrule
}{}

\begin{document]

\begin{quiz}{course}{title}
  \q{10} test1
  \q{10} test2
\end{quiz}

\end{document}



You could simplify your example to
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{quiz}{\begin{document}}{\end{document}}


\begin{quiz}
  x
\end{quiz}


which produces
! LaTeX Error: \begin{quiz} on input line 5 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \end{quiz}
              
?

and if you scroll past that,
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 5 (\begingroup)
### bottom

document isn't really an environment (it does not form a group) it would be possible in principle to define a top level quiz environment by using internal details of the document implementation to work around the above errors, but really you should not. Human readers of your source, and mechanical syntax checkers, code highlighters, etc will all expect to see \begin{document} to separate the preamble from the document body, and while you could make a top level quiz environment technically work for LaTeX, you can't avoid that that's a confusing LaTeX document syntax.
